# Cadence pSpice weird simulation results

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, orcad, cadence

I made two simulations of real opamp and ideal opamp, why are results so different if other params are the same?

[image: Ideal]
[image: Real]

Model I took from maxim site http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/tools/modeling-simulation/spice/operational-amplifiers/orcad/MAX4239.LIB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three obvious problems with your circuit.

1) Assuming you want a differential amplifier, you need to feed back the output to the - input, not the + input. To see why this makes a difference, add a little AC to V1, and watch the output swing from rail to rail. As part of the simulation process, the simulator has produced a solution for inputs/outputs at turn-on. This does not imply that the solution will remain stable for changes in inputs, and if you change them you will see that your circuit does not have a gain of 10.

2) You are grossly violating the MAX4239 input common mode limits. Your inputs should be no more than Vcc - 1.3 volts. See the data sheet.

3) You are violating the maximum supply voltage rating for the MAX4239. Maximum total supply voltage is 5.5 volts.

Comment: Big thanks for reply and you are right about 2, other things I need to check. Also, article about section 2 can be useful for someone http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=528175

Answer (score 0):

Op amps have offset voltages and leakage currents. These will be different between different amplifier designs, and the models should reflect this. If you use different models, expect slightly different results.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well, I suppose there are difference between real and ideal op amp, but it cannot explain my results. Op amp configured on gain 10, and ideal op amp is working perfectly here, it have a 10 gain, but real amplifies signal by 50. May be something wrong with the maxim model, in pspice a didn't get any errors.

Comment: CybGeen, you have positive feedback in your circuits (no negative feedback), which never can work in practice. However - please note that such a problem cannot be revealed using an ideal opamp for ac simulations. To compare both circuits - and to proof stability properties - you must do a simulation in the time domain (TRAN simulation)

Comment: CybGen, from what follows that the gain is 10 or 50? It seems to me you haven't done any analysis except for _DC Bias point calculation_, or am I wrong? As LvW already noted your main problem is you have mistaken OpAmp inverting and non-inverting inputs, so it can't work as you expect (that's why I think you haven't simulated it yet; AC Sweep or Transient analysis)

Comment: Gain should be 10, and ideal model works fine here, I went over limit op amp input voltage. WhatRoughBeast answered about it.

Comment: CybGen, OK, but you have still mistaken inverting and non-inverting inputs in your circuit, so in reality it will not work properly due to instability.